# Having trouble adding class to a div whilst building Tic Tac Toe game

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom-events

I've looped through the divs and added event listeners to each of them.
I'm now trying to add a class to the div when its clicked. I can successfuly add the class if i target the tile by ID but I want to add the class to the tile that is clicked.

```
var gameBoard = document.getElementsByClassName("tile")
var playerOne = {
"turn": true,
"class": "cross" 
}

var playerTwo = {
"turn": false,
"class": "naught" 
}
for (let i = 0; i < gameBoard.length; i++ ) {
gameBoard[i].addEventListener("click", takeTurn)
}


function takeTurn () {
this.classList.add(playerOne.class)
}
```

If I store a tile in a variable using getElementById then use

```
tileOne.classList.add(playerOne.class)
```

it works fine. but every div clicked would just change tile ones class and not the targeted click.

I'm still fairly new to programming so I think I'm missing something. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

When you add a listener you receive event data as arguments in the function called.
So, you have to change your function takeTurn with:

```
function takeTurn (event) {
    event.target.classList.add(playerOne.class)
}
```

event.target select the element that trigger the event.